# How to solve NullInjectorError: No provider for A?

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm working with Angular but in production on the server, I get this error:

```
https://daphneprojects.nl/invoices see here at this link.
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError[A -> A]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[A -> A]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for A!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError[A -> A]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[A -> A]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for A!
    at A.get (main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1)
    at main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1
    at A (main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1)
    at A.get (main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1)
    at main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1
    at A (main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1)
    at A.get (main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1)
    at Dn (main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1)
    at A.get (main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1)
    at gi (main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1)
    at k (polyfills.49ef6fea8d1bad7c3dc1.js:1)
    at k (polyfills.49ef6fea8d1bad7c3dc1.js:1)
    at polyfills.49ef6fea8d1bad7c3dc1.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.49ef6fea8d1bad7c3dc1.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.2023b441a151556b775e.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.49ef6fea8d1bad7c3dc1.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.49ef6fea8d1bad7c3dc1.js:1)
    at g (polyfills.49ef6fea8d1bad7c3dc1.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.49ef6fea8d1bad7c3dc1.js:1)
    at f (polyfills.49ef6fea8d1bad7c3dc1.js:1)
```

Locally I don't have this error, what can this be? 
I don't know what code to show, because the exception is so abstract..

Answer (score 1):

apparently you are using one service in one module but this service was not injected correctly in the module file. Check in the module file if you put the service like a  provider of that module.

Comment: Yes I did, but I'm going to write a simple component now with implementation of the service to check if it's the service itself.. or maybe a plugin / package that i'm using.. I'll give an update soon.

Comment: I've found the problem, it was due to awesomefont. See my answer in this post.

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to awesomefont 
`import { faEuroSign } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';`

this module: 
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';